# How to convert value from HTML table to JSON array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```html
    <table style="width:100%;   border-collapse: collapse;  text-align: center;" id="stockinboundedittable">
      
        <tr>
          <th style="display:none;">subcategory</th>
          <th>Sl.No</th>
          <!--<th>I.U.Code</th>-->
          <th>Item Name</th>
          <th> old stock</th>
          <th> new stock</th>
          <th> Total Stock</th>
          <th> qrt</th>
          <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
     
      <tr>
        <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_2</td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound1" value="1" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname1" value="Fresh Goat Meat - Curry Cut" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock1" value="20" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock1" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock1" value="30" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty1">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut1">EDIT</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_5</td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound2" value="2" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname2" value="Everest - Kasur Methi" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock2" value="0" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock2" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock2" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty2">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut2">EDIT</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_13</td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound3" value="3" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname3" value="Fresh Coconut Milk 150 ml" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock3" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock3" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock3" value="20" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty3">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut3">EDIT</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_5</td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound4" value="4" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname4" value="Sakthi - Chicken Masala" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock4" value="20" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock4" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock4" value="30" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty4">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut4">EDIT</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_2</td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound5" value="5" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname5" value="Goat Bones - Regular Soup Pack" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock5" value="0" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock5" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock5" value="10" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty5">
        </td>
        <td>
          <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut5">EDIT</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    </table>
```

##i need to read values inside  tag and save it like json array with sl.no and edit button excluded in json array##

```
[{"itemname":"Chicken Drumstick","oldstock":"20","newstock":"10","totalstock":"30"},
{"itemname":"Chicken Drumstick","oldstock":"0","newstock":"10","totalstock":"10"},
{"itemname":"Chicken Drumstick","oldstock":"10","newstock":"10","totalstock":"20"},
{"itemname":"Chicken Drumstick","oldstock":"20","newstock":"10","totalstock":"30"},
{"itemname":"Chicken Drumstick","oldstock":"0","newstock":"10","totalstock":"10"}]
```

*the above json array is the example format i needed

- i need to read it with loop from whole table

Comment: Do you actually want it as JSON, or as a JS array of objects?

Comment: [{"itemname":"Chicken Drumstick","oldstock":"20","newstock":"10","totalstock":"30"},
{"itemname":"Chicken Drumstick","oldstock":"0","newstock":"10","totalstock":"10"},
{"itemname":"Chicken Drumstick","oldstock":"10","newstock":"10","totalstock":"20"},
{"itemname":"Chicken Drumstick","oldstock":"20","newstock":"10","totalstock":"30"},
{"itemname":"Chicken Drumstick","oldstock":"0","newstock":"10","totalstock":"10"}]. I like to have data like this

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't answer the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job:

```js
const res=[...document.querySelectorAll("#stockinboundedittable tr")].slice(1).map(tr=>
[...tr.querySelectorAll("input")].slice(0).map(inp=>[inp.id.replace(/.*inboundedit/,"").replace(/\d+$/,""),inp.value]))
.reduce((a,c)=>{
  a[c[0][1]]=
  Object.fromEntries(c.slice(1));
  return a},{}); 

console.log(res[2]);
```

```html
<table style="width:100%;   border-collapse: collapse;  text-align: center;" id="stockinboundedittable">
  
    <tr>
      <th style="display:none;">subcategory</th>
      <th>Sl.No</th>
      <!--<th>I.U.Code</th>-->
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th> old stock</th>
      <th> new stock</th>
      <th> Total Stock</th>
      <th> qrt</th>
      <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
 
  <tr>
    <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_2</td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound1" value="1" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname1" value="Fresh Goat Meat - Curry Cut" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock1" value="20" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock1" value="10" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
    <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock1" value="30" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut1">EDIT</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_5</td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound2" value="2" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname2" value="Everest - Kasur Methi" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock2" value="0" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock2" value="10" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
    <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock2" value="10" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty2">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut2">EDIT</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_13</td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound3" value="3" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname3" value="Fresh Coconut Milk 150 ml" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock3" value="10" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock3" value="10" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
    <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock3" value="20" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty3">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut3">EDIT</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_5</td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound4" value="4" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname4" value="Sakthi - Chicken Masala" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock4" value="20" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock4" value="10" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
    <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock4" value="30" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty4">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut4">EDIT</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="display:none;">tmcsubctgy_2</td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="slno1editinbound5" value="5" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedititemname5" value="Goat Bones - Regular Soup Pack" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditoldstock5" value="0" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditnewstock5" value="10" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
    <input style="    width: 100%;" id="stockinboundedittotalstock5" value="10" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="    width: 100%;" id="inboundeditqty5">
    </td>
    <td>
      <button style="background: #fdd110; width: 100%;" id="stockinboundeditditbut5">EDIT</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</table>
```

I have a nested `.map()` loop that will collect both, the `id`s and the `value`s of each input field (apart from the first one in each row). The `Object.fromEntries()` call will then assemble the inner arrays back into objects, using the first array element as the key and the second one as the value.

My answer also doesn't return a JSON string but an array of objects instead. Simply put it through `JSON.stringify()` if you *really* want a JSON string.

**Update**
Following OP's latest comments I updated my answer. I now use the first column as an "Id-key" and create an object of objects instead of an array of objects. The Id-key can be used to address each menu individually, as can be seen in my example `console.log()` where I selected the menu with Id-key `2`.

Comment: it working perfectly ,
How can i get only first row or second row with row id ......

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
   function table_to_array(table_id) {
            myData = document.getElementById(table_id).rows
            //console.log(myData)
            my_liste = []
            for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
                    el = myData[i].children
                    my_el = []
                    for (var j = 0; j < el.length; j++) {
                            my_el.push(el[j].innerText);
                    }
                    my_liste.push(my_el)

            }
            return my_liste
    }
```

Comment: May you wait until the OP clarifies the question? This doesn't return JSON.

Comment: [{"itemname":"Chicken Drumstick","oldstock":"20","newstock":"10","totalstock":"30"},
{"itemname":"Chicken Drumstick","oldstock":"0","newstock":"10","totalstock":"10"},
{"itemname":"Chicken Drumstick","oldstock":"10","newstock":"10","totalstock":"20"},
{"itemname":"Chicken Drumstick","oldstock":"20","newstock":"10","totalstock":"30"},
{"itemname":"Chicken Drumstick","oldstock":"0","newstock":"10","totalstock":"10"}].      I like to have data like this format like json array or objects

Comment: @A.Chithrai do you want the data in JS, or as a string?